# Why would Hibernate ignore package-info.java?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, usertype

I'm trying to use Hibernate @TypeDef annotation on a package level, exactly as it is described in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2794).
I'm using `Hibernate 3.6` and `Spring 3.0.7`. The code compiles and the `package-info.class` is in the classpath, but still it is not seen by the Hibernate.

If I put `@TypeDef` on the class level, it's working, but not if I put in the `package-info`. I tried to google but couldn't find anything helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably need to add a

```
<resource package="com.foo.bar.thepackage"/>
```

to your Hibernate config file, or to call [configuration.addPackage("com.foo.bar.thepackage")](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addPackage%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: That works, thanks!
I'm using `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`, so adding `<property name="annotatedPackages">`helped.

Comment: Using Hibernate 3, and NOT the `AnnotationSessionFactory`, I had to make the `configuration.addPackage('bla.bla.com')` call - that worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can add this hibernate mapping entry with EntryManagerFactory  ex: <bean id="entryManagerFactory" class="org.Springframework.orm.jpa.HebernateVendorAdaprter">

 <property name= JpaProperties>

   <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.cfg.configuration"> com.foo.bar.thepackage </prop>
    <props>
 </property>

<bean>

Answer (score 2):

For Hibernate 4, you have to add

```
<mapping package="com.foo.bar.thepackage">
```

to your Hibernate config file.

Answer (score 2):

If using JPA, using

```
<class>com.foo.bar.thepackage</class>
```

in the persistence.xml also should work.

Comment: this worked for me, i am using persistence.xml. according to jboss docs class attribute in section 2.2.1. Packaging:https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/#architecture

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to a bug in Spring, where it doesn't scan the annotations in package-info, but only those on classes annotated with @Entity, @Embeddable, or @MappedSuperclass. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8589.

Comment: Fixed in version 3.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: For people having this issue, I recommend looking through the comments of [SPR-8589](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8589). While some issues were resolved in Spring 3.2.2, using it with JPA didn't really start working until Spring 4.1 or even later. Also look through the comments of linked ticket [SPR-10910](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10910).