# How to configure package level @TypeDefs with Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I need to configure @TypeDefs for use custom @Type on package level. When I configured it following manner I am getting ClassNotFoundException. But when I put @TypeDefs on the class level it is working fine.

I have found similar kind of [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637887/why-would-hibernate-ignore-package-info-java) but I haven't any idea to how to configure `<resource package="com.foo.bar.thepackage"/>` entry with my application-context.xml file.

According some post (as bellow), noted this a Spring related [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8589)

```
I believe this is due to a bug in Spring, where it doesn't scan the annotations in package-info, but only those on classes annotated with @Entity, @Embeddable, or @MappedSuperclass. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8589.
```

Can any one help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

**@TypeDefs declaration with package-info.java**

```
@TypeDefs
        ({
                @TypeDef(
                        name="encryptedString",
                        typeClass=EncryptedStringType.class,
                        parameters={
                                @Parameter(name="encryptorRegisteredName",
                                        value="abcHibernateStringEncryptor")
                        }
                )
        })

package com.abc.core.model;

import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
import org.jasypt.hibernate4.type.EncryptedStringType;
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<!-- ############################### General Configurations #################################################### -->

<!-- Enable annotation-driven configuration and auto-detection -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Enable Spring configuration-detection -->
<context:spring-configured/>

<!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc"/>

<!-- Configure property placeholders for environment-specific properties customization -->
<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true" location="classpath*:/project.properties"/>


<!-- ############################### Persistence Related Configurations ######################################## -->

<!-- JPA adapter -->
<bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
</bean>

<!-- EntityManager factory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.abc.core.model" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>                
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- JPA repositories -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.abc"
                  transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

<!-- Use @Transactional annotation on methods -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

<!-- ## JASYPT related configurations ## -->

<!-- jasypt encryptor for string -->
<bean id="abcStringEncryptor"
      class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="algorithm">
        <value>PBEWithMD5AndDES</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>XXX</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- hibernate encryptor for string -->
<bean id="theHibernateStringEncryptor"
      class="org.jasypt.hibernate4.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="registeredName">
        <value>abcHibernateStringEncryptor</value>
    </property>
    <property name="encryptor">
        <ref bean="abcStringEncryptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Entity class with custom @Type mapping**

```
package com.stee.rcm.core.model;

@Entity
@Table(name = "trail")
public class Trail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue 
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Type(type="encryptedString")
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
}
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : encryptedString
```

Comment: Anyone has a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I too faced same issue, It seems spring have some issue to scan TypeDef when they are at package-info.java class.

Declaring resource in the configuration is nothing but packagesToScan.You have already used in your configuration and even this does not help in scanning TypeDefs.

```
<resource package="com.foo.bar.thepackage"/>
```

We can go with any of below approaches

1. Declare TypeDef in each pojo classes(where ever userType/CustomType is used).
2. Explicitly register CustomType to hibernate configuration.This can be done in two ways:

   1. Registering CustomType programmatic.
           configuration.registerTypeOverride(new EncryptedStringType(),new String[]{"encryptedString"});
   2. Declaring TypeDef in session factory bean configuration and extending local session factory bean.

> Spring.xml :

```
<bean id="DateTypeSessionFactory" class="com.runtime.data.factory.TypeResolverSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DateTypeDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.p27.datetype"/>
        <property name="customTypes">
            <array value-type="com.runtime.data.CustomType">
                <ref bean="dateTimeCustomType"/>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    ${DateType.dialect}
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                    false
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers">
                    false
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">
                    ${DateType.hbm2ddl}
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistentLocalDateTimeType" class="com.studio.common.data.type.WMPersistentLocalDateTime"/>
    <bean id="dateTimeCustomType" class="com.runtime.data.CustomType">
        <property name="type" ref="persistentLocalDateTimeType"/>
        <property name="keys">
            <list>
                <value>DateTime</value>
                <value>org.joda.time.LocalDateTime</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    public class CustomType {

    private UserType type;
    private String[] keys;

    //getters & setters

    }
```

> SessionFactoryBean :

```
public class TypeResolverSessionFactoryBean extends LocalSessionFactoryBean {

    private CustomType[] customTypes;

    @Override
    protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sfb) {
        if(customTypes != null) {
            registerCustomTypes(sfb);
        }
        return sfb.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    protected void registerCustomTypes(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sfb) {
        for (CustomType customType : customTypes) {
            sfb.registerTypeOverride(customType.getType(), customType.getKeys());
        }
    }

    public void setCustomTypes(CustomType[] customTypes) {
        this.customTypes = customTypes;
    }
}
```