# Kotlin package level TypeDefs for Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin

I have a custom type for hibernate (`TipoSiNo`), this is the equivalent of the `YesNoType` but for spanish (S/N).

When using java I declared this type as the default for boolean fields in a package-info.java file:

```java
@TypeDefs(@TypeDef(name = "si_no", typeClass = TipoSiNo.class, defaultForType = Boolean.class))
package com.xyz;

import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs;

import com...TipoSiNo;
```

This worked fine for java entity classes but when I convert them to kotlin I got an error:

```
Data conversion error converting "'S'...
```

So I supossed I had to convert the package-info file to kotlin:

```
@file:TypeDefs(TypeDef(name = "si_no", typeClass = TipoSiNo::class, defaultForType = Boolean::class))

package com.xyz

import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs

import com...TipoSiNo
```

But even then it does not seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where/How do You Add Documentation for Kotlin Packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212451/where-how-do-you-add-documentation-for-kotlin-packages)

Answer (score -1):

There is currently no equivalent of `package-info.java` for Kotlin. As a workaround, you can simply include a `package-info.java` in Kotlin and it will be processed.

If you are using Spring Boot, you may run into this additional issue: [How to configure package level @TypeDefs with Spring Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358609/how-to-configure-package-level-typedefs-with-spring-hibernate) :

> It seems spring have some issue to scan TypeDef when they are at package-info.java class.